# Select for update skip locked from JPA level

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, locking, eclipselink

In my application - Oracle with JPA (EclipseLink), I'm using the following expression to lock the subset of the records in some tables:

```
select * from MY_TABLE where MY_CONDITIONS for update skip locked
```

I run it throughout native query, but I have to write that query for all required entities.

Is there any way to skip locked records using pure JPA? Can I implement my own locking policy?

I don't mind changing JPA provider but I want to use JPA API.

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/locking_and_concurrency_in_java ?  That is really not how JPA is intended to be used.  Locking entire tables is a scalability killer.  Maybe re-think what it is you are trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: I agree, I'm not locking entire table, this select was an example. I use this approach to avoid locking entire table. I lock subset of the data that is intended to be updated next. I want to ignore already locked records because if the other process picked it up they are not longer relevant for updating.

Comment: I don't see a way to do it with pure JPA except with native queries as skip locked is Oracle-specific and not supported by JPA.You can probably get it done using a custom Dialect (for Hibernate, there should be a similar feature for EclipseLink), but you would still need to communicate that you want a specific query to use the feature.

Comment: Hibernate provides LockMode.UPGRADE_SKIPLOCKED that does the job, but that is not supported by JPA. Perhaps you can get the job done by mixing Hibernate and JPA, but it sounds messy!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hibernate provides the UPGRADE_SKIPLOCKED Lock mode.

Using JPA and Hibernate, to produce a "SKIP_LOCKED" as per [Hibernate LockMode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/locking/Locking.html#locking-LockMode) documentation, you have to combine the *PESSIMISTIC_WRITE* JPA [LockModeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html):

```
entityManager.find(Department.class, 1, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

and the Lock timeout setting, like for example in persistence.xml for your persistence unit:

```
<properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="-2"/>
</properties>
```

(Note that you can configure this LockMode for complex query as well)

SKIP LOCKED is not part of ANSI SQL. Some RDBMS such the following provide this as a specific feature:

- [MySQL](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/)
- [Postgresql](http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-5-feature-highlight-skip-locked-row-level/)
- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55270)

So with pure JPA, it is not possible to specify a "SKIP LOCKED" in queries.
Indeed, as documented in [LockModeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html), JPA 2.1 only supports the following:

- NONE
- OPTIMISTIC
- OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT
- PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT
- PESSIMISTIC_READ
- PESSIMISTIC_WRITE
- READ
- WRITE

However, to enable SKIP LOCKED in your query you can use these alternatives:

- Use specific JPA implementation feature, such as [Hibernate LockMode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/locking/Locking.html#locking-LockMode) which allows to specify the SKIP LOCKED via a JPA query, thanks to a combination of *PESSIMISTIC_WRITE* LockModeType Lock Timeout specific setting as described above
- Create a native SQL query as you did

Comment: Yes, "select mailqueue0_.id as col_0_0_ from mailqueue mailqueue0_ where mailqueue0_.date<now() order by mailqueue0_.date for update nowait" - this is what we get with  setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0)

Comment: @MaksimGumerov, your javax.persistence.lock.timeout setting  is not correct. You have to set "-2" instead of "0", as documented in the answer,  to produce a "for update skip locked". This is how it works with Hibernate when using JPA. So what  are you trying to achieve exactly by setting it to 0?

Comment: I see now. I somehow failed to see that you mentioned that this way is also specific to Hibernate, even despite being formally expressed in JPA settings. My bad. Removed most of my prior comments.

Comment: Huh, a query timeout of `-2` (which applies to all queries?) as an indicator to use `SKIP LOCKED`? Strange idea.

Answer (score 9):

For spring JpaRepository, this can be used:

```
String SKIP_LOCKED = "-2";
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = AvailableSettings.JPA_LOCK_TIMEOUT, value = SKIP_LOCKED))
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
List<YourEntity> fooBar();
```

works well on Oracle, not sure about others

Comment: What is the significance of -2?

Comment: @Kevvvvyp its explained in other comments to this question. My answer is just a snippet for spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is a bit old, but for the record, just as the accepted answer stated, "javax.persistence.lock.timeout" (`org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings#JPA_LOCK_TIMEOUT`) set to "-2" (`org.hibernate.LockOptions#SKIP_LOCKED`) with Hibernate results in "SKIP LOCKED". However, this can be done at run-time without having to set any global settings.

Since 2.0 JPA [allows to pass hints](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-java.util.Map-) along like so

```
entityManager.find(MyType.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", "-2");
    }});
```

Comment: Here is a way to do it in spring-data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058253/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-skip-locked-rows-postgresql?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't provide a read lock, since it doesn't need one; undo logs make it unnecessary. So, SELECT...FOR UPDATE is really just a WRITE lock for Oracle.

Using JPA, you want to set the LockModeType as a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE.

Comment: This is not a read lock, it's an update lock that you obtain while doing a read. The net result is that other updates block but not reads.

Comment: @PawelZieminski read my answer again; I'm not saying what you think I am.