# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate Skip Locked rows (PostgreSQL)

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to execute SKIP LOCKED query on PostgreSQL using Spring Data JPA (2.1) and Hibernate. The query looks like this:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value ="-2")})
List<Obj> findByEntityAndStatus(Entity entity, Status status);
```

According to [Spring data JPA native query skip locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208705/spring-data-jpa-native-query-skip-locked) and [Select for update skip locked from JPA level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434169/select-for-update-skip-locked-from-jpa-level) it should work but the generated query only selects for update without skipping locked rows.

The generated query:

> Hibernate: select obj0_.id as id1_5_, obj0_.name as name6_5_, obj0_.entity_id as entity10_5_, obj0_.status as status8_5_ from objs obj0_ left outer join entities entity1_ on obj0_.entity_id=entity1_.id where entity1_.id=? and obj0_.status=? for update of obj0_

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem since then ? ^^'

Comment: @Janar can you select the correct answer if that helps?

Answer (score 7):

Your code is fine. All you need to remember is that PESSIMISTIC_WRITE uses a `SELECT …​ FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` in Oracle and **PostgreSQL 9.5**. I assume you could have forgotten about telling JPA, that you what to use newer version of Postgres. So you have two options:

- tell JPA that you are using PostgreSQL Dialect which supports `SKIP LOCKED`:

  ```
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
  ```

  After this I received desired output:

  ```
  where
      subscripti0_.valid_until<=? 
  and subscripti0_.status='ACTIVE' 
  for update of subscripti0_1_ skip locked
  ```

  and obviously, concurrent thread was was not able to fetch locked rows until transaction was completed.
- use native query :

  ```
  SELECT * FROM objects o WHERE o.valid_until <= :validUntil FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nativeQuery.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM task LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED", nativeQuery = true)
List<TaskEntity> fetchAllUnlocked();
```