# How I can achieve SKIP LOCKED functionality using pessimistic lock?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I want to implement skip lock. I am using postgres 9.6.17. I am using the following code

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "-2")})
@Query("Select d from Demo d where d.id in (?1)")
List<Demo> getElementByIds(List<Long> ids);
```

I am making the same DB call from 2 services at the same time through cmd(parallel Curl request to both services which make DB call). From 1 server I am passing ids from 1...4 and from other I am passing ids from 1.....7. 
But in case if the first service takes a lock on 1...4 row and then the second service has to wait until first service removes its lock but ideally, the second service should return rows 5...7
From the first service I am calling like this

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add(1l);
    ids.add(2l);
    ids.add(3l);
    ids.add(4l);
    List<Demo> demos = demoRepo.getElementByIds(ids);
    try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    logger.info("current time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and from the second service I am calling like this:

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add(1l);
    ids.add(2l);
    ids.add(3l);
    ids.add(4l);
    ids.add(5l);
    ids.add(6l);
    ids.add(7l);
    try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    logger.info("current time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    List<Demo> demos = demoRepo.getElementByIds(ids);
    logger.info("current time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

But always both the queries returning the same rows which I am asking after waiting for another service to release the lock.

Spring JPA version I am using :

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
```

I have also tried at the application level itself spring.jpa.javax.persistence.lock.timeout=-2  that also not working.
Both the methods seems to working like PESSIMISTIC_WRITE.

Please suggest how I can achieve skip locked functionality.

Comment: Are you sure there is concurrency on the calls. Note that the `Thread.sleep` is outside the context of the call to the repository, so may be just the call is fast enough and there isn't concurrency at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Queries seem to be correct.

Hope you are using latest Dialect of Postgres which supports Skip Lock functionality.

Considering the version of Postgres you are using, below Dialect should be used.
*org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect*

You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058253/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-skip-locked-rows-postgresql) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Answer of RAVI SHANKAR was correct. I have tested and it realy worked. You need to specify dialect version.
For example in spring boot

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
```

Also code will be more readable if you use constants insted of strings.

```
@QueryHint(name = AvailableSettings.JPA_LOCK_TIMEOUT, value = LockOptions.SKIP_LOCKED.toString())
```